# React native, let me know the this.props.navigation.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to retrieve the data to B.claa from A.class.
When I make directly a button in return in Class A. 
the data from A can be retrieved into B class to show up.

However, when I make a function to make buttons, using for-loop,
the data is not really going to be retrieved. It is just undefined..

here, there Class A and B. 
so basically, in class A , there is 5 buttons linking to class B's screen 
B Screen should get the data from A to show up in its screen.

Please let me know this solution..

Class A.

```
const renderButtons = (navigateG) => {
const views = [];
const Name= ["AB","BC","cd","ef","gg"]
for ( var i =0; i<5; i++){
views.push(
<Button
   key={i}
   onPress={() => navigateG('B', { 
                    Title:"hi",
                    Name:Name[i],

                })}
   title="Learn More"
   color="#841584"
   accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>);
} // % buttons are created. 

return views;
}
export default class A extends Component {

 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'A',
    headerLeft: <MenuButton navigation={navigation}/>
});

render() {  
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;    
    return ( 
     renderButtons(navigate) )
 }
     </ScrollView>

    );
 }
}
```

Class B.

```
export default class B extends Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.Title}`
});
render(){return(   <Text>{ this.props.navigation.state.params.Name }</Text> )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Name of navigation state using `this.props.navigation.state.params.Name`  not `this.props.navigation.state.Name`

Comment: hello, I finally found why it is undefined, as you can see onPress={() => navigateG('B', { 
                    Title:"hi",
                    Name:Name[i],

                })} in views of rendererbutton. name[i] can't be really retrieved.

Comment: when I put   console.log(this.props.navigation.state) in B class, it prints out object{ key:".....", Title:"hi", Name:undefiend ....}'